# Format all data as Text (not General) when exported to Excel

Tags: excel, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report with no column format settings. It's a blank slate. When I export to Excel, all cells have the "General" format.

The problem is that I need all cells in the spreadsheet to have the "Text" format. Is there anything I can do on the SSRS side so that all cells in the spreadsheet have the "Text" format, and not the "General" format?

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit your data on report to have single quote (')  on the first position.
Excel numbers, dates, and others non texts ('81111231456)  recognize as text.

Comment: Good idea, but did not work. The resulting Excel file still has everything in general format, and all cells have a visible leading single quote.

Comment: @dev_etter I know it is stupid and non profesional but can you in excel try replace ` with ` then excel after replace with same caracter doing reformating cells.

Comment: Can you reword that and/or clarify? I can't completely understand what steps you're asking me to take.

Comment: @dev_etter Way I cope with that is that I at exported excel docs with leading quotes ' using excel replacing qutes (') with qutoes (') that users doing manually when open excel document in MS Excel

Comment: I don't see the reason to do that. If I can't programmatically encode the entire worksheet as Text format, I'd just ask the user to highlight all cells and change the format from General to Text.